# How can i use post request in pecl_http library

Tags: httprequest, pecl

[hotelbeds api](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/apitude_activities_booking/search_request)

The api required to use post request with some fields, but i don't know where are the fields will be added!! ( in GET request i add the fields in the url like any request )

the api code

`

```
$apiKey = "8z8a7tupn5hubhjxqh8ubuz7";
$sharedSecret = "jsSJq2msbU";
$signature = hash("sha256", $apiKey.$sharedSecret.time());

$endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/activity-api/3.0/activities";

$request = new \http\Client\Request("POST",
    $endpoint,
    [ "Api-Key"     => $apiKey,
    "X-Signature" => $signature,
    "Accept"      => "application/json" ,
    ]);


$client = new \http\Client;

$client->enqueue($request)->send();

$response = $client->getResponse();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response->getBody());
    echo "</pre>";
```

the api said

> The available filters for the search is listed below.
>
> It contains an array of filter with the following structure:
>
> [{"searchFilterItems": [{"type": "destination", "value": "BCN"}]}]
>
> The Object “searchFilterItems” contains the following attributes: type > and value.
>
> The following examples illustrate the different types and values for > each filter:
>
> Country
>
> {"type": "country", "value": "PT"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, took me a little while to figure it out. Turns out you need to use the Body class to represent the post data.

```
$msg = new http\Message\Body();
$msg->addForm([
  'field1' => 'value',
  'field2' => 'value2'
]);

$headers = null;

$request = new http\Client\Request('POST', 'https://example.com', $headers, $msg);

$client = new http\Client();
$client->enqueue($request);
$client->send();

$response = $client->getResponse();
```

There are some more methods available in the Message and Body class for including files, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$request = new http\Client\Request;
            $body = new http\Message\Body;
            $body->append('{Your JSON}');
            $request->setRequestUrl('https://api.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0 hotels');
            $request->setRequestMethod('POST');
            $request->setBody($body);
            $request->setHeaders(array(
                'Accept'                        => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/json',
                'Api-Key'               => $owapiKey,
                'X-Signature'               => $signature,
              //'Accept-Encoding'   => 'Gzip',  //Deflate
              'cache-control'       => 'no-cache'
            ));

            try {
                $client = new http\Client;
                $client->enqueue($request)->send();
                $response = $client->getResponse();

                if ($response->getResponseCode() != 200) {  
                echo("HTTP CONNECT FAILURE: -> ".
                $response->getTransferInfo("effective_url").
                $response->getInfo().$response->getResponseCode() );
            } else {
                            $res=$response->getBody()->toString();
                         }              

            } catch (Exception $ex) { echo("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n".$ex->getMessage()); }
```